# Как убрать \n из массива js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

```
{"cards1":["\n    aaaaaaaaaaaa\n  ",null],"cards2":["\n    bbbbbbbbbbb   \n  ","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/858585/000000.png"],"cards3":["\n    cccccccccccccccc\n  ",null],"cards4":["\n    dddddddddddddddd\n  ",null]}
```

в массив добавляются лишние не нужные \n

использую такой код , чтобы их убрать,  но пишет , что `arr.filer is not a function` arr это наш массив

```
arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== "\n";
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.replace(/\n/g,'');
});
```

Comment: *arr это наш массив*- то, что в начале вопроса, не массив

Comment: `filer !== filter`

Comment: Впрочем, у вас всё равно не массив, а объект.

Comment: То, что вы написали в первой строчке: `{"cards1":["\n aaaaaaaaaaaa\n ",null],"cards2":["\n bbbbbbbbbbb \n ","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/858585/000000.png"],"cards3":["\n cccccccccccccccc\n ",null],"cards4":["\n dddddddddddddddd\n ",null]}` Не является массивом, поэтому и ошибка. Вот пояснение разницы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097851/difference-between-var-and-var

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку , сейчас посмотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это дело можно организовать так, но replace выдает ошибку, если элемент == null. Поэтому рядом добавленая пустая строка || "" (а после циклов, все null превращаются в "")

```js
var obj = {
  "cards1": ["\n    aaaaaaaaaaaa\n  ", null],
  "cards2": ["\n    bbbbbbbbbbb   \n  ", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/858585/000000.png"],
  "cards3": ["\n    cccccccccccccccc\n  ", null],
  "cards4": ["\n    dddddddddddddddd\n  ", null]
}


for( var key in obj ){
  obj[key].forEach(function(e,i){
    obj[key][i] = (e||"").replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"");
  });
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
```

спец-символ `\s` находит пробелы... а `*` означает "ноль или несколько совпадений". Оно убирает в том числе и пробелы до и после \n

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь . Пошло

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  "cards1": ["\n    aaaaaaaaaaaa\n  ", null],
  "cards2": ["\n    bbbbbbbbbbb   \n  ", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/858585/000000.png"],
  "cards3": ["\n    cccccccccccccccc\n  ", null],
  "cards4": ["\n    dddddddddddddddd\n  ", null]
};

for (let prop in obj) {
  obj[prop].forEach((item, i, arr) => {
    if (!(typeof(item) === 'string')) return;
    arr[i] = item.replace(/\n/g, "");
  })
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь . Тоже ,как и ответ выше, работает

Comment: @XXXXXX, ага, только он еще и пробелы удалил) всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: я заметил насчет пробелов